# Why does loading images asynchronously take forever?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView displaying a bunch of images. If I don't load the images asynchronously the scrolling is very choppy and provides a poor user experience. When I load the images asynchronously the scrolling is smooth but it takes a good 5 to 10 seconds to load each image.

Why does it take so long for images to appear when loaded in the background? Here is my code for the background thread which is inside of the cellForItemAtIndexPath delegate:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImageView *bg = (id)self.backgroundView;
    UIImageView *selbg = (id)self.selectedBackgroundView;

    if (![bg isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];
    else
        [bg setImage:thumb];

    if (![selbg isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        selbg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];
        coloroverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:selbg.bounds];
        [coloroverlay setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [selbg addSubview:coloroverlay];
    } else
        [selbg setImage:thumb];

    [bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [bg setTag: 1];
    [coloroverlay setBackgroundColor:[col colorWithAlphaComponent:0.33f]];
    [selbg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setBackgroundView:bg];
        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:selbg];
    });
});
```

EDIT: As @geraldWilliam pointed out, I shouldn't be accessing views from the secondary thread. Here is what I have updated my code to and fixed the issue of images getting set to the wrong cell:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImageView *bg = (id)self.backgroundView;
    UIImageView *selbg = (id)self.selectedBackgroundView;

    if (![bg isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];

    if (![selbg isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        selbg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];
        coloroverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:selbg.bounds];
        [coloroverlay setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [selbg addSubview:coloroverlay];
    }


    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [bg setImage:thumb];
        [selbg setImage:thumb];

        [bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [bg setTag: 1];
        [coloroverlay setBackgroundColor:[col colorWithAlphaComponent:0.33f]];
        [selbg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

        [self setBackgroundView:bg];
        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:selbg];
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a little dangerous doing UI stuff (which might trigger layout calls) from a background thread.  You are manipulating views which are already in a view hierarchy, and calling methods which normally also have a side effect of calling [self setNeedsLayout] or [self setNeedsDisplay] etc. (such as setImage: and addSubview: and setContentMode:). Those latter ones probably need to be done in the main thread, and maybe the main thread only.

Comment: I recommend you to use `AFNetworking` and lets this framework does the task for you. I am quite happy with the `caching`, `threading` and other `optimizations` implemented in this library.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the code you have here is fine for the main queue. The loading of the image should be on a global queue, but the rest, especially setting the image view's image, should be on the main queue. What's going on in your code is that you're dispatching back to the main queue to set the background view but leaving the assignment of the image property in the background. So, try something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL]];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageView.image = image;
    [self setBackgroundView:imageView];
  });
});
```

Comment: Gerald is quite correct that you should not be accessing views in any way from a secondary thread, that will crash at some point. The logic above will do the image data IO in the background thread, but keep in mind that it does not actually alloc mem and start to decode the pixels inside the image buffer until you actually access a pixel. The above is an improvement over what you were doing, but the image pixels still get decoded in the main thread the first time the pixels are accessed when the image is rendered.

Comment: I did this and it does work better but it still takes a while to populate the cells with images. I think it's because it's trying to populate even those cells that aren't visible.

EDIT: Nvm no it's not.

Comment: You can check whether a cell is visible by checking for a nil return value from -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]. Using a third party library like AFNetworking or SDWebImage would probably be advisable, though. Then, you can just say something like [myImageView setImageWithURL:myURL]; And the decoding and caching and all of that gets handled for you.

Comment: @geraldWilliam awesome thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend watching [WWDC 2012 Session 211: Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211), which is the best WWDC session ever. It’s full of clearly presented, practical advice.

Doing stuff with `UIImageView` off the main queue is worrying and should be fixed, but is probably not the cause of slowness. You haven’t showed us where `thumb` comes from, which is likely the slow bit.